# Does using fact tblname in all DAX fucntions result in table expansion?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Given a model with fact table having multiple dimension tables, Does using the fact tblname in all DAX fucntions result in table expansion?

Example:

SUMX(tblname, expr)

CALCULATE(expr, FILTER(tblname, criteria))

Comment: what do you mean by table expansion? both SUMX and FILTER are iterators, the difference here is that in first case `expr` is evaluated for each row of `tblName` and then summed, while in the second case you change the filter context based on criteria (iterating with FILTER), and pass the result as new filter context in CALCULATE which evaluates `expr` only for that specific filter context. Which will have the same result for `expr=SUM(tblName[column])` (just faster), but can be different for more complex calculations

Comment: I'm trying to understand whether table expansion occurs.

Comment: [This](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/context-transition-and-expanded-tables/) may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when a relationship exists, there is an expanded table.

In the first example

```
SUMX(tblname, expr)
```

the iterator creates a row context over the tablname. RELATED must be used to access fields in the `tblname` expanded tables that are not parte of tablename, but reachable through a many to one relationship.

in the second example

```
CALCULATE(expr, FILTER(tblname, criteria))
```

the `FILTER` is an iterator and therefore it works like in the first example.

The table returned by FILTER inside `CALCULATE` acts as an expanded table, therefore affecting not only the existing filters over tblname, but also the existing filters over the columns that are part of the tblname expanded table.

For instance, assuming to have a model with a table Customers and a table Sales with a one to many relationship between Customers and Sales, in this code

```
CALCULATE([Sales Amount], FILTER(ALL(Sales), Sales[Quantity] > 2))
```

the FILTER returns a filtered Sales expanded table that removes any existing filter over Customers table.